# How might I build a negative attribute selector in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, null, css-selectors

I am experimenting (might be foolhardy) with reproducing in **CSS** what Douglas Crockford refers to as a **bottom value**.

> ***What's a bottom value?***
>
> In Javascript, bottom values are `undefined` and `null`.

I can take a custom-data attribute:

```
data-my-custom-attribute=""
```

and I can give it a value of **null** (using Unicode `U+2400`):

```
data-my-custom-attribute="␀"
```

In CSS, I can then reference any custom-data attribute which *is* **null**:

```
[data-my-custom-attribute="␀"] {

  [... CSS PROPERTIES HERE...]

}
```

Next up, I'd like to deploy an equivalent to this Javascript:

```
if (myCustomAttribute !== null) { ... }
```

But it seems I *can't* reference any custom-data which *isn't* **null**, because something like ***this***:

```
[data-my-custom-attribute!="␀"] {

  [... CSS PROPERTIES HERE...]

}
```

doesn't work and isn't valid.

---

Having established that:

- `[data-my-custom-attribute!="␀"]`

doesn't work, it occurs to me that:

- `[data-my-custom-attribute]:not([data-my-custom-attribute="␀"])`

actually *does* work (and if nothing else comes up, I'll stick with that).

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.rectangle {
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: orange;
}

[data-my-custom-attribute="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}

[data-my-custom-attribute="yellow"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

[data-my-custom-attribute="blue"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

[data-my-custom-attribute="␀"] {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

[data-my-custom-attribute]:not([data-my-custom-attribute="␀"]) {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div data-my-custom-attribute="red"></div>
<div data-my-custom-attribute="yellow"></div>
<div data-my-custom-attribute="blue"></div>
<div data-my-custom-attribute="␀"></div>

<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

However,

```
[data-my-custom-attribute]:not([data-my-custom-attribute="␀"])
```

feels awkward and verbose. Is there really nothing better?

Comment: it doesn't feel that awkward and verbose and it seems to be the only solution since you have 2 conditions to fulfill

Comment: Re: _"it doesn't feel that awkward and verbose"_ I like `[attribute!="value"]` much more than `[attribute]:not([attribute="value"])`.

Comment: even if the first exist you still need the condition that `attribute`  *exist* so it will be `[attribute][attribute!="value"]` unless you define it to work only on existing attribute

Comment: That's not the case with `[attribute^="value"]`, `[attribute*="value"]`, `[attribute$="value"]` etc.

Comment: it's not the same. To have an attribute equal to something, it need to exist (you cannot have a non-existing attribute equal to something) but the not equal apply to non-existing attribute since if the attribute doesn't existe then it's for sure not equal to that value.

Comment: What you are describing (as we both know) is analagous to the difference between a variable not being defined in javascript and a variable being defined but having a value of `null`. I have shown this in my example, above where `div.rectangle` does not have the attribute `data-my-custom-attribute` while the fourth `div` has it, but its value is `␀`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a more concise way. Even jQuery's `[att!=val]` selector, which has remained exclusive to jQuery all these years, doesn't require that the attribute be present to match, so you'd still need to pair that with `[att]`.

I understand this is an experiment with the bottom value concept, but for the sake of completeness I'll add that the closest things to a null attribute value in HTML (and by extension CSS) are either the empty string (the default value of custom data attributes), or the *lack* of the attribute entirely. The idiomatic way to achieve your desired result is to choose either the empty string or omission of the attribute altogether, and use a corresponding `[data-my-custom-attribute=""]` or `:not([data-my-custom-attribute])` selector respectively in CSS, and `if (myCustomAttribute === "")` or `if (("myCustomAttribute" in myDiv.dataset) === false)` respectively in JS.

Comment: Thank you, @BoltClock. I definitely want to draw a distinction between the attribute being present and having a value of `␀` and the attribute being absent entirely. My first thought when I started putting my experimental UI together was to use `""` as the `null` value, but I decided early on, that in order not to bake in potential future problems, I needed `""` to be a valid non-`null` value (just as `''` in javascript is a valid non-`null` value).

Answer (score 5):

Right. Conclusions.

Just as there already exist in CSS the following attribute selectors:

- `[data-attribute="value"]` // *has `data-attribute`, the value of which **is** `value`*
- `[data-attribute^="value"]` // *has `data-attribute`, the value of which **begins with** `value`*
- `[data-attribute*="value"]` // *has `data-attribute`, the value of which **contains** `value`*
- `[data-attribute$="value"]` // *has `data-attribute`, the value of which **ends with** `value`*

I was hoping there might be something like:

- `[data-attribute!="value"]` // *has `data-attribute`, the value of which **is not** `value`*

and then, by extension:

- `[data-attribute!^="value"]` // *has `data-attribute` and its value **doesn't begin with** `value`*
- `[data-attribute!*="value"]` // *has `data-attribute` and its value **doesn't contain** `value`*
- `[data-attribute!$="value"]` // *has `data-attribute` and its value **doesn't end with** `value`*

---

But, instead we only have:

- `:not([data-attribute="value"])` // *value **is not** `value` **OR** no `data-attribute`*
- `:not([data-attribute^="value"])` // *value **doesn't start with** `value` **OR** no `data-attribute`*
- `:not([data-attribute*="value"])` // *value **doesn't contain** `value` **OR** no `data-attribute`*
- `:not([data-attribute$="value"])` // *value **doesn't end with** `value` **OR** no `data-attribute`*

---

So the only way to get rid of the alternative possibilities (ie. after logical **OR**) is:

- `[data-attribute]:not([data-attribute="value"])` // *`data-attribute` value **is not** `value`*
- `[data-attribute]:not([data-attribute^="value"])` // *value **doesn't begin with** `value`*
- `[data-attribute]:not([data-attribute*="value"])` // *value **doesn't contain** `value`*
- `[data-attribute]:not([data-attribute$="value"])` // *value **doesn't end with** `value`*

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selectors are selected with attributes like example:

**Example:**

```
<style>
   a[target="_blank"] {
      background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hariom. This is a good start. Please keep up your positive contributions to Stack Overflow. All the best.